# How to develop “360 flat image view” in “panorama view” for web application

Tags: panorama-control, panoramas, photosphere

My friend wanted me to find “360 jpg image (Taken by phone) in panorama mode in web application”. What would be the best technology for develop that module.

Are there are any open source technology/libraries, reference materials or any tutorials?

Answer (score 0):

For Android, you can try this demo 
[Try GoogleCardBoard Sample](https://github.com/pollux-/GoogleCardBoardVr-360-PhotoSphere)

Answer (score 0):

Try including this to your `build.gradle`

```
compile 'com.gjizhe:PanoramaImageView:1.0'
```